# GoogleMaps in Mono For Android 4.0 on Mac

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android

I'm trying to run the samples of xamarin about googlemaps, and the MapsDemo sample doesnt work. I'm trying to run on the google api 8 emulator, it throws me this error: Couldn't get connection factory client, and when im trying to run on google api 10 emulator:

```
W/System.err(  555): IOException processing: 26
W/System.err(  555): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
W/System.err(  555):    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

and my apiKey is correct. Does anyone have this working with googlemaps with monodroid on mac? If you do, how can I solve this? Because I have already spent a long time trying to solve this one but I cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The default emulators do not ship with the Google API's.  When you create your emulator, you will need to choose a target like:

Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 8

Comment: Im using that and the Google APIs 2.3.3, in both of them doesnt work.